# GHCI character limit?

Tags: haskell, emacs, runhaskell

I'm using `ghci` to do some incremental development using Emacs' `run-haskell`. Every once in a while, I get an error that looks like

```
<interactive>:[line]:[character]: _Lexical error at character '\EOT'
```

Setting up an intermediate variable or two gets a working response, and the file I'm working on both loads and compiles properly. Reducing character count also works; the max I seem to be able to hit is 252.

Anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Comment: [There's this mailing list post about it too.](http://projects.haskell.org/pipermail/haskeline/2009-May/000018.html) (Which leads to [this (closed) bug](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3256).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [filed and closed](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3256) as a bug in GHC several years ago, so looks like no dice on fixing it at the GHCi end. (Searching "_Lexical error at character '\EOT'" gives a few other results ([for example](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.agda/914)), but I can't work out how applicable they are.)